# How do I capture the submit event of a Google Form in a child iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a Google Form embedded in an iFrame in an html page. The parent DOM needs to know when the form has been submitted so it can then allow progress onto the next part of the webapp. The form is embedded using the script exported from the Google Form embed menu option:-

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1blablabla/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

I am hoping to be able to capture the onSubmit event using javascript but I am unsure how to do this. I have looked through the docs but have found little tangible help in there for my situation.

Any guidance, tips or advice much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately for security reasons ) this is impossible :P

Comment: @CodingAnt Thanks! Yeah I thought the cross-domain situation would be a deal breaker but I wondered if there was an alternative solution or approach....